# C++ behaves differently in Qt, bind() returns EINVAL

Tags: python, c++, qt, sockets, qlocalsocket

**I have already checked out [bind() return EINVAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56100493/bind-return-einval) and that is not the issue here. Please read through before you get furious about duplication.**

I am trying to connect to `wpa_supplicant`. Basically I'm trying to achieve this using C++:

```
import os
import select
import socket

interface = "wlp4s0"
wpa_send_path = "/run/wpa_supplicant/"+interface
wpa_recv_path = "/tmp/wpa_ctrl_{pid}-{count}".format(pid=os.getpid(), count=1)

soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, 0)
soc.bind(wpa_recv_path)
soc.connect(wpa_send_path)

print("> PING")
soc.send(b"PING")
print("<", soc.recv(4096).decode().strip())
```

*from https://gist.github.com/artizirk/cd3980c8ff870eb0bfce68bc26a2676b*

And I have done what I wanted but using plain C++. This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/un.h>

#define PATH   "/run/wpa_supplicant/wlp4s0"
char path[100] = "/tmp/wpa_ctrl_";

int main(void) {

  int ctrl_socket;
  char buffer[1024];
  struct sockaddr_un socket_addr, send_addr;

  memset(&socket_addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
  memset(&send_addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));

  socket_addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
  send_addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;

  strcpy(send_addr.sun_path, PATH);

  strcat(path, std::to_string(getpid()).c_str());
  strcat(path, "-1");
  strcat(socket_addr.sun_path, path);

  if ((ctrl_socket = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) {
    std::cerr << "Error creating socket!" << std::endl;
    std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  /* Unlink if already bound */
  unlink(socket_addr.sun_path);

  if ((connect(ctrl_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&send_addr, SUN_LEN(&send_addr))) == -1) {
    std::cerr << "Error connecting to socket!" << std::endl;
    std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  if (bind(ctrl_socket, (const struct sockaddr *)&socket_addr, offsetof(struct sockaddr_un, sun_path) + strlen(path) + 1) == -1) {
        perror("Error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  send(ctrl_socket, "PING", 5, 0);
  recv(ctrl_socket, buffer, 1024, 0);

  std::cout << buffer << std::endl;

  close(ctrl_socket);

  return 0;
}
```

This code works fine. But when I do it in Qt, `bind()` always return `EINVAL` i.e `Invalid Arguments`. Here's that code:

```
WPASupplicantControl::WPASupplicantControl(std::string wlan_interface_name)
    :wpa_send_ctrl_iface(WPA_SEND_CTRL_IFACE_PREFIX + QString::fromStdString(wlan_interface_name)),
      wpa_recv_ctrl_iface(
          WPA_RECV_CTRL_IFACE_PREFIX +
          QString::fromStdString(std::to_string(getpid())) +
          "-1"
          )
{
    struct sockaddr_un send_address, recv_address;

    send_address.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    recv_address.sun_family = AF_UNIX;

    memset(&send_address, 0, sizeof (send_address));
    memset(&recv_address, 0, sizeof (recv_address));

    strncpy(send_address.sun_path, wpa_send_ctrl_iface.toStdString().c_str(), wpa_send_ctrl_iface.length());
    strncpy(recv_address.sun_path, wpa_recv_ctrl_iface.toStdString().c_str(), wpa_send_ctrl_iface.length());

    if ((wpa_control_socket = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) {
        qCritical() << "socket() failed!";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Attatch to sending and receiving control interfaces */
    if (connect(wpa_control_socket, (const struct sockaddr *)&send_address, SUN_LEN(&send_address)) == -1) {
        qCritical() << "Error connecting to wpa_supplicant send control iface!";
        close(wpa_control_socket);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Detatch if it's already bound */
    unlink(recv_address.sun_path);

    if (bind(wpa_control_socket, (const struct sockaddr *)&recv_address, offsetof(struct sockaddr_un, sun_path) + wpa_recv_ctrl_iface.length() + 1) == -1) {
        qCritical() << "Error binding to wpa_supplicant recv control iface!";
        close(wpa_control_socket);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

**A functional dummy project to test this code is at: https://github.com/gaurav712/socket_test**

I have checked all the values hundreds of times and they're all fine but still it doesn't work. It just goes upto that `connect()` call.

I thought I should use something Qt-specific and I found out about **QLocalSocket** https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocalsocket.html but when I import it, Qt doesn't recognize that class. Maybe its because I'm on Qt 6.x and it is now deprecated(although I didn't find any official deprecation notice thingy). What do I do? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The third parameter to `bind` looks odd.  Shouldn't it be `sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)`?

Comment: @G.M. - you should make that the answer. I would upvote that.

Comment: @G.M. Have a look at the linked question, that's exactly what I thought initially, but then it wasn't working even in plain c++ so I did some research and found out that it should be that *long odd parameter*. `SUN_LEN` should work too, I guess, just like the `connect()`. And most importantly, I've tried `sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)`, didn't work.

Comment: I have no idea where you learned that `offsetof` is the way to calculate the length parameter of your address.  It should be what G.M. suggested: `sizeof(sockaddr_un)`

Comment: @selbie As I said mate, I started with `sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)`, it didn't work. And for the source of `offsetof`, look at the comment by *Remy Lebeau* on the question linked to the post.

Comment: I see the issue, your `strncpy` is suspect.

Comment: BTW, I tried to reproduce and I got EINVAL inside QT class CTor, and also when invoking that normally inside main.

Comment: @selbie `man unix(7)` suggests that `offsetof` as well. About that `strncpy`, it could be the reason but I've checked the final path and it's fine.

Comment: It would be nice to see a [mcve].  Having said that, what happens if you change `bind` to `::bind` to force resolution in the global namespace?

Comment: @G.M. still nothing.

Comment: @G.M. I have added link to a barebone Qt project with this code(see the edits). You can reproduce it now.

Comment: The Qt way of handling Unix sockets is, BTW, to use a *QAbstractSocket* and assign a manually created socket descriptor to it using *QAbstractSocket::setSocketDescriptor()*

Comment: Absolutely nothing to do with Qt: You do a `memset` to all-0 of the sockaddr structures **after** you've set the socket's family to AF_UNIX (which is "1! on most platforms). How should the system know you want a local socket?

Comment: @tofro My bad. You're right, I didn't notice that sequence in the Qt version. Post it as the answer so I can approve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely nothing to do with Qt: You do a `memset` to all-0 of the sockaddr structures **after** you've set the socket's family to `AF_UNIX` (which is "1" on most platforms). How should the system know you want a local socket?

Answer (score 0):

`strncpy` will copy at most `n` bytes from source to dest.  If there's no null char within n bytes, it's not going to copy it over.  The third parameter to strncpy is usually meant to convey the length of the destination buffer.

Change this:

```
strncpy(send_address.sun_path, wpa_send_ctrl_iface.toStdString().c_str(), wpa_send_ctrl_iface.length());
strncpy(recv_address.sun_path, wpa_recv_ctrl_iface.toStdString().c_str(), wpa_send_ctrl_iface.length());
```

To be this:

```
strncpy(send_address.sun_path, 
        wpa_send_ctrl_iface.toStdString().c_str(),
        sizeof(send_address.sun_path) );

strncpy(recv_address.sun_path,
        wpa_recv_ctrl_iface.toStdString().c_str(),
        sizeof(recv_address.sun_path));
```

Also, as discussed in the comments, your length param to `bind` looks funky as well. Try it both with the above changes.

Comment: Tried with both of those changes. No luck! It must be something Qt-related as I've attatched a non-qt code that works just fine.